# Position elements in normal flow below a fixed element

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have a fixed element that is positioned within the center of the page:

```
.class {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

No matter the screen size, this element always appears dead center within the browser. However, is there any way to have my regular flow of content always begin just after it?

I've considered just putting a simple spacing div, but since this element is variably centered, I'm not sure what the best way would be to anticipate where it'll always be.

Comment: so you want some kind of preloader in this modal ?

Comment: @srekoble what does a preloader have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS3 `calc()` function to set `height` property for a spacer element, in order to push the content box down:

```css
.spacer {
    height: calc(50% + 150px); /* 50% of screen + 1/2 of the height of the box */
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="class">The fixed box</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="content">Content goes here...</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/NHWRD/)**

Answer (score 0):

If it's `position: fixed` it will not affect the regular flow of your elements. It specifically has it's own context.

You'd need to position the other content dynamically via javascript, something like below can be placed directly after the element that needs to be shifted.

```
<script>
    document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.style.marginTop = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.clientHeight + 'px';
    //# sourceURL=AP_ThemeTemplateA.page-inlinedScript1
</script>
```